# MongoDB - problema com divergência de dados no aggregation

Tags: mongodb

Estou fazendo um `agreggation` na `collect` `pedidos` onde no final eu faço um `group` para fazer a contagem de quantos `pedidos` tem cada status. 
Até ai, tudo certo...

Só que quando eu coloco no `match` a procurar um `status` específico ele acha mais dados do que quando não é setado valor do `status` no `match`;

```js
[
  {
    '$match': {
      '$and': [
        {
          'created_at': {
            '$gte': new
            Date(
            'Wed, 01 May 2019 00:00:00 GMT'
            ),
            '$lte': new
            Date(
            'Sat, 01 Jun 2019 00:00:00 GMT'
            )
          }
        },
        {
          'status': 'ATIVO'
        },
        {
          '$or': [
            {
              'deleted_at': null
            },
            {
              'deleted_at': {
                '$exists': false
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    '$sort': {
      'created_at': -1
    }
  },
  {
    '$group': {
      '_id': '$msisdn',
      'order': {
        '$last': '$$ROOT'
      }
    }
  },
  {
    '$match': {
      'order.status': 'ATIVO'
    }
  },
  {
    '$group': {
      '_id': '$order.status',
      'count': {
        '$sum': 1
      }
    }
  }
]

//output
_id:"ATIVO"
count: 3097

[
  {
    '$match': {
      '$and': [
        {
          'created_at': {
            '$gte': new
            Date(
            'Wed, 01 May 2019 00:00:00 GMT'
            ),
            '$lte': new
            Date(
            'Sat, 01 Jun 2019 00:00:00 GMT'
            )
          }
        },
        {
          '$or': [
            {
              'deleted_at': null
            },
            {
              'deleted_at': {
                '$exists': false
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    '$sort': {
      'created_at': -1
    }
  },
  {
    '$group': {
      '_id': '$msisdn',
      'order': {
        '$last': '$$ROOT'
      }
    }
  },
  {
    '$group': {
      '_id': '$order.status',
      'count': {
        '$sum': 1
      }
    }
  }
]

// output
_id:"ATIVO"
count: 2737
```

Comment: Você está começando perceber porque o modelo relacional ainda é muito melhor para a maioria das aplicações.

Comment: Capaz, sempre pensei isso, mas, tem situações que não temos escolhas :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[SOLUÇÃO]

O `$sort` está perdendo dados antes do `$group` que puxa os últimos pedidos.

```
{
  _id: '$msisdn',
  "order": {
    "$last": "$$ROOT"
  }
}
```

no meu caso apenas troquei de posição o `$sort` e funcionou corretamente.